# What is the difference between team foundation server's "Client" and "WebApi" libraries?

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, azure-devops

I'm writing C# to interface with TFS to manipulate Work Items in TFS. The existing code I'm working with is exclusively using **Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi** but from what I see in examples online, the library everyone is using is [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130323(v=vs.120).aspx) and [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WebApi.Client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitem(v=vs.120).aspx)

From what I can infer, the WebApi library is providing only a limited functionality - for instance, I can't create an attachment and associate it to a WorkItem - but, this does appear to be possible with the Client library. Before changing a lot of code to do this, I'm really just interested in knowing what's the underlying difference between these libraries.

Any insight into the TFS client libraries would be much appreciated.

Comment: I also found this link from someone outside of SO... https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2015/08/10/nuget-packages-for-tfs-and-visual-studio-online-net-client-object-model/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mainly difference is that Client libraries (SOAP API) use [Legacy Client Object Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146(v=vs.120).aspx) while WebApi libraries calls the [New Rest API](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/integrate/api/overview) to achieve the functions.

And the mainly limitation with these two APIs:

1. Client libraries cannot work well with the new vNext build system.
2. WebApi cannot perform update action (For example check in changes) with Version Control, it can only read information for now.

The WebApi can create an attachment and associate it to a Workitem, you need to updolad the attachment to VSTS by call "CreateAttachmentAsync" method and then call "UpdateWorkItemAsync" method to add the uploaded attachment to a work item. It is following a same workflow as the Rest API: [Upload an attachment](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/attachments#upload-an-attachment) and then [Add an attachment](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#add-an-attachment).

Comment: Thank you so much for this information. This was my hunch, but I couldn't find anything to confirm that COM was a legacy approach. The COM library exposes a much "nicer" interface to the application programmer - probably because it's more mature at this point. But, I suppose that's a matter of preference. WebApi seems to leak the REST/JSON I/F to the client. It would be nice to have a strongly-typed, fully encapsulated library that hid the details of JSON from the client.